# How To Programmatically Rotate The Camera In The A-FRAME Scene?

Tags: aframe

I would like to programmatically rotate the camera in the A-FRAME scene in a similar way that you can click and drag the mouse to rotate the camera around the scene.  Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

In case when `look-controls` component is used, it will override the rotation of the camera element, so one has to set internal attributes of the `look-controls` component.

Overriding mouse control rotation value in that component can be done like this:

```
aCamEl.components['look-controls'].pitchObject.rotation.set(THREE.Math.degToRad(pitch),0,0);
aCamEl.components['look-controls'].yawObject.rotation.set(0,THREE.Math.degToRad(yaw),0);
```

Answer (score 0):

A more detailed description of the problem will help you get a more precise answer. A-Frame already lets you click and drag the mouse to move the camera via the [look-controls component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/look-controls.html#sidebar) . There's also a component called [orbit controls](https://github.com/tizzle/aframe-orbit-controls-component) that rotates the camera around a target point. If you want to implement your own, create a and apply a [component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html) to the camera that manipulates its rotation on the [tick](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/component.html#definition_lifecycle_handler_methods_tick) method

```
tick: function () {
  this.el.object3D.rotation.set(...);
}
```

You apply your component in the HTML as follows:

```
<a-entity camera your-component></a-entity>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out what was causing the issue.  Essentially, I was trying to rotate my camera rig on load, but my WASD controls were inverted when doing so.  In addition, I was using the aframe-extras.js library.  I removed the library, added the `wasd-controls` attribute to my camera and set my camera rig to `cameraRigEl.setAttribute("rotation", "0, 180, 0");` and everything worked as expected.